# Cannot delete an article in crud app (mongo, express, Nodejs)

Tags: node.js

Hi I am trying to make a crud app using Node Express and mongodb. But when I am trying to delete an article from my app it says it cannot delete. I checked all the code but cant find errors. Can anyone help please?
[image]

Delete route in my code is

```
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res)=>{
    await Article.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

Link to delete an article is

```
<form action="/articles/<%=article.id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                </form>
```

This is my server.js file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `app.use(methodOverride("_method"));` middleware before routing `app.use('/articles', articleRouter)`